# pathspec 'README.md' did not match any files

Tags: git, github

When I use the command: `git add README.md` inside the folder of my project I get the message:  `pathspec 'README.md' did not match any files`

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a file named README.md first? Git won't create the file itself with the `add` command, since all that does is add the file to the index, but you can do so with `touch README.md`.